# loop through div elements with same class, and getting the values

Tags: jquery

I have the following html:

```
<input id="box20" name="rooms[]" value="20" class="box" type="checkbox">
<div>68.00</div> € / night
<input id="box21" name="rooms[]" value="21" checked="checked" class="box" type="checkbox">
<div class="specialprice">68.00</div>€ / night
<input id="box22" name="rooms[]" value="22" class="box" type="checkbox">                                                        
<div>155.00</div> € / night

<h4>Total: <div class="newprice"></div></h4>
```

I want to get the values of the div(s) with class specialprice and I want to show the sum in another div named newprice.

I am trying with following javascript, but I am getting blank alert so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $('.specialprice').each(function() {
   x = $('.specialprice').innerHTML;
   alert(x);
 });
```

});

If the class is just , I am not interested to get that value, what I want is to get all prices from divs named specialprice and to make sum from those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are alerting the array:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.specialprice').each(function(i, el) {
       x = $(el).html();
       alert(x);
    });
});
```

Comment: I get uncaught type error:undefined is not a function

Comment: Sorry, `.html` is a method of jQuery, i edited it as `x = $(el).html();`, try now.

Comment: Hi Teh...now the code works. But how can i get the sum of all checked checkbox? Can you give me a hand with this?

Comment: You want the sum of the html of the divs with class `specialprice`? Or you want the sum of the `value` of the checked checkboxes?

Comment: I want the sum of all div's with class special price.

Comment: [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/85ZT4/), notice i setted `class="specialprice"` to 2 divs.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var addPrice;
$('.newprice').text(function(){
  return $('.specialprice').each(function(){
      addPrice += parseInt($(this).text(),10);
  });
});
```

Comment: No this will return NAN

Comment: Exactly Anto. I just test this code, and returns NaN

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `$(this)` variable to access the current element - [Reference to the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/each/) - otherwise you'll have a collection instead of the correct element.

```
var prices = [], sum = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.specialprice').each(function() {
        var currentItem = $(this);       // Reference to the current item
        prices.push(currentItem.text()); // or .innerHTML, method to get the text
   }

   prices.forEach(function(entry) {
        sum += parseInt(entry);          // Otherwise it would be a string Concatenation
   }

   $('.newprice').text(sum);
});
```